# how does iis 7 generate etags

Tags: iis, iis-7, etag

what method/algorithm does iis 7 use to generate etags. I'm looking for exact, not 'well they use checksum on the date'

This leaves lots of questions. What algorithm for checksum, which date, which format of the date (short, utc, 'mm-dd-yyyy ttad', 'MMDDDYYY', etc)

Thanks in advance. i have scoured the net and cannot find this answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ETag generated by IIS has two parts

Filetimestamp:ChangeNumber

according to

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922703/

As you noticed, the algorithm is not publicly available. But why you are interested in this? Unless you create an IIS clone.

Comment: Well, we are having an issue with the same server(no cluster, farm, garden, etc) returning one of 2 etags. Very odd. So i'd like to know what file time stamp it's using for the 2 etags. It's always the same etags, but it serves them up at different times.

Comment: Can you show some examples? What was returned by IIS and what was expected by you? Thanks,

Comment: For very same resource that `ChangeNumber` part used to change with server computer in case of load balanced environments until IIS 6.0. From IIS 7.0 onwards it defaults to `0`.

Comment: `ChangeNumber` is a counter used to track configuration
changes to IIS on any given server.

Comment: Well that's not going to work very well for server farms that replicate using dFSR, where dates do not copy if the file does not change....