# How to generate 'last-modified' http header for a resource?

Tags: http, nginx, http-caching, last-modified

I currently read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified) about '`last-modified`' HTTP header. Though I have read number of sources, I'm still confused how it is generated for a particular resource.

Is it solely depends on the time stamp when the resource has changed in the db. i.e. as PUT requests are processed for the db. on the same resource?

Or are there any generalized or nearly generalized logic to tackle the problem?

And the generation of `last-modified` time, is it solely a responsibility of the actual application? or are there any other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in [my answer about `ETags`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47524911/2395796), the responsibility to provide the header always lies with the resource provider.

And just as with `ETags`, there may be ways that the web server or framework can automate the creation of the header. By far the most common case is that web servers serving static files can use the files' modification time to set the `Last-Modified` header.

It's harder to automate with dynamic applications, since there's generally not a standard source of that information. To take an example I'm familiar with, Django allows you to [specify a function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/conditional-view-processing/#the-condition-decorator) that will be called to get the `Last-Modified` date. It's up to you to put the application-specific logic into that function, but the framework will populate the header and do the comparison to return `Not Modified` responses.

My impression is that most dynamic applications don't bother with the `Last-Modified` header. If you have to provide custom logic to figure out the caching headers, you might as well just provide the `ETag`, which is generally preferred. Also, with `ETags` you can often avoid doing any application-specific logic at all if the framework will hash the response for you.

Comment: make sense. Unfortunately there are very online sources which have addressed this context. Perhaps, because those things are not mandatory. So in your answer, you are telling that 'perhaps there are frameworks', but you don't aware any of them right?

Comment: @SupunWijerathne: No, I don't know of any frameworks for dynamic applications that can fully automate the population of the `Last-Modified` header. I added an example of how Django does it, which is I think is probably about the most you can do.